# Single sign-on using a hosted service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, openid, single-sign-on

I am to create a small single sign-on solution for a small site I am making. My requirements are that the user should be able to login using Facebook or OpenId. I can't figure out if I should find a free third party hosted single signon solution, if available, or if I should code it myself.

Do you usually create the single signon solution for a small site yourself, or find a 3rd party option?

For a large solution I wouldn't have hesitated to create it myself, but since it is just a small site for fun, it might be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing libraries cover everything you need so you don't have to create much.

Using either http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ or http://www.janrain.com/products/engage you're doing almost the same amount of work to wire everything together.